# How Can I Do 302 Redirect On Blogger

Tags: javascript, php, html, blogger, http-redirect

I want to do a 302 redirection on blogger but the codes that I found online does not transfer the link juice even though it works. What am I doing wrong?

```
<meta charset='utf-8'/>
<meta content='0;url=https://www.yournewsite.com/' http-equiv='refresh'/>
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl'>
 <link href='https://www.yournewsite.com/' rel='canonical'/>
</b:if>
```

Comment: does it work from control panel? https://www.wikiijunction.com/redirect-a-post-page-in-blogger/

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty Blogger is quite a vast service to include something for redirection.

Nevertheless, here you can add this to the very top of your page, inside `<head>`

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
  window.location.replace("http://www.example.com");
</script>
```

**HTML-based**

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;
      url=http://example.com/" />
</head>
```

It should execute as soon as the script is accessed, therefore redirecting even before the page fully loads.

**EDIT**
Sorry, my bad, didn't see you needed specifically a 302 Redirect.